# Cuál es el error de sintaxis en este código?

Tags: python, sintaxis

hice este código en python esperando que al **preguntar sobre un numero del 1 al 10, la respuesta sea si "te ama" , "mas o menos" o "no te ama"** pero al correrlo en mi consola me envía un error de sintaxis, se que puede ser muy tonto pero si alguien me ayuda a entender puede que llegue mas rápido a ser un buen programador, justo ahora estoy en la frustración de algo que parece muy fácil, muchas gracias.

```
    amor = int(input('Escribe un numero del uno al diez: '))
    if amor>= 9:
        print('Ella te ama')
    elif numero == 5:
        print('mas o menos')
    else 
        print('no te ama')
     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Edita y agrega el error que te muestra

Comment: En el elif de la linea 4 -> numero no existe como variable

Comment: Intenta con `elif amor == 5:`en la linea cuatro

Comment: Cual es el error que te arroja? eso ayuda bastante para corregir el problema

Answer (score 2):

Tú código presenta dos errores principales:

1. La variable `número` no está definida, por lo que, al ejecutar el código verás el mensaje correspondiente al `input` recogido por la variable amor, es decir, el mensaje **"Escribe un número del uno al diez"**, pero si a continuación ingresas un valor, la ejecución se detendrá lanzado un error, esto se debe a la ejecución secuencial de instrucciones. El usar una variable no definida produce un error de tipo `NameError`, el cuál se vería:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in run
    elif numero == 5:
NameError: name 'numero' is not defined
```

Este error nos indica que el nombre **'numero'** no está definido, no se ha implementado.

2. La instrucción `else` precisa de `:` para evitar de esta forma un error de tipo `SyntaxError`, el cuál se vería similar a:

```
File "main.py", line 7
        else
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Por tanto, atendiendo a estos dos errores, el código resultante sería:

```
def run():
  amor = int(input('Escribe un número del uno al diez: '))
  if amor >= 9:
    print('Ella te ama')
  elif amor == 5:
    print('más o menos')
  else:
    print('no te ama')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

Por último, personalmente, te recomiendo que todas tus **clases**, **métodos**, **funciones**, **variables**, etc sean **autodescriptibles**, es decir, cuyo nombre sea fácilmente reconocible para el objetivo a cumplir. Esto compone un concepto que oirás mucho y son las **"Buenas Prácticas de Programación"**.

Un ejemplo sería la siguiente operación. Si dispongo de tres variables y quiero llevar acabo una operación con ellas, no es lo mismo que yo nombre a estas tres variables como:

```
t = p * r
```

que asignarles un nombre un poco más **legible** como:

```
total = precio * porcentaje
```

en ese caso, si más adelante quiero **reutilizar código** podré saber que referencia esas variables, esto ahorra **tiempo y traumas**.

Por ende, atendiendo a esta **práctica**, tu función podría tener el nombre de `love()` por ejemplo, ya que veo que está relacionado con el amor:

```
def love():
  amor = int(input('Escribe un número del uno al diez: '))
  if amor >= 9:
    print('Ella te ama')
  elif amor == 5:
    print('más o menos')
  else:
    print('no te ama')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
  love()
```

Comment: Para corregir algunos problemas de sintaxis que te puedan surgir, te recomiendo que si estás usando algún IDE tipo PyCharm instales un **linter**, Python provee uno bastante popular llamado **Linter PyLint**. Saludos